# Transconductance of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, transconductance

I am trying to understand this formula to find the transconductance of a MOSFET transistor, but I am not getting the passage from the second to the third line. What happened there?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Try this video: [Transconductance of MOS in strong inversion](https://youtu.be/8diFH6xhc4c) This video explains MOSFET gm from basic definitions and then explains the various equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basis is the following approximate equation for the drain current (Wikipedia):

[image]

Taking the partial derivative gave gm as a function of (Vgs-Vth). One can express (Vgs-Vth) as a function of Id reversing the base equation. By inserting that one gets your problematic third line.