# In jfet, how can VGS(off) be found with just IDSS and gm0?

Tags: jfet

Transconductance curve of jfet is a parabola.

Given a point (0, IDSS) and
gm0, which is the slope at VGS=0,

how is it possible to find the VGSOFF ? One point and slope give a straight line, not a parabola right? My textbook says it can be found:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm too lazy to do the math properly but to me it looks like they're simply extrapolating the \$I_D\$ at \$V_{GS}\$ = 0, using the slope = \$gm\$ to find the point where \$I_D\$ = 0. That means they assume the JFET behaves **linear** with the reference point \$I_D\$ at \$V_{GS}\$ = 0. That indeed disregards the more realistic parabolic behaviour. But in many cases, that's good enough.

Comment: Similar question has been asked before: [Transconductance of a MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/335818/transconductance-of-a-mosfet)